# $authWithOAuthPopup() doesn't work on mobile

Tags: firebase, angularfire

The following does not open a popup/new tab/do anything on Chrome 39.0.2171.50 for iOS 8.1.2 (12B440),
 however it does seem to work on Safari on the same device:

```
<button ng-click="$auth.$authWithOAuthPopup('facebook')">Login with Facebook</button>
```

See plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ejd7fsyTHf6Ohn0F25Wy?p=preview

Is this a bug with Chrome or Firebase/AngularFire or am I doing something incorrectly?

I see from [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/8vwtH1P9l_w) that this may be a Chrome issue, however I can't get `$authWithOAuthRedirect()` to work either; see: http://plnkr.co/edit/9dd0W8X5k33LFBcCLmzs?p=preview

Both Popup and Redirect work on Desktop Chrome 39.0.2171.95

Comment: I had the same problem with safari on Yosemite. Ended up using $authWithOAuthRedirect.

Answer (score 4):

Firebase does not support popups are all platforms. In the event that an unsupported platform is detected, the `authWithOAuthPopup()` method will return an error with the code `TRANSPORT_UNAVAILABLE`, indicating that you should try to authenticate with a different transport, such as a browser redirect.

Comment: Fair enough. Is that in the docs somewhere? Do you know specifically what causes this to fail in some browsers?

Comment: @MurraySmith Unfortunately, it is not well documented, but appears in a few places in the Firebase docs, such as the [Error Listing](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html).

Comment: Unfortunately, some browsers do not support the necessary features for this transport. PhoneGap / Cordova / Ionic require a shim (the InAppBrowser plugin) in order to use `window.open`. Chrome is similarly disabled in iOS because it has historically not had a reliable transport for `window.open(...)` in combination with secure, cross-frame postMessage. Similarly, redirects are not available for PhoneGap / Cordova apps because there is no mechanism to redirect the browser from an external, public-internet URL back to the local filesystem where the PhoneGap app is loaded from.

Comment: Hey @Rob, I just ran into this issue again and was wondering if there's been any update in this behaviour since I last checked. Thanks!

Comment: @MurraySmith No change, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Iam not sure of ios but if you use android device along with ionic and firebase, run the following command to fix the issue:

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
```